# PERL Can't locate object method "echo" via package "IO::File" at ./echo.pl

Tags: perl

I'm learning Perl by following the book "Learning Perl the Hard Way" by Allen B. Downey. It instructs me to execute the following code "echo.pl":

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

sub echo {
    my @params = @_;
    print "@params\n";
}

echo ARGV
```

Testing the code returns:

```
$./echo.pl TEST NOW
Can't locate object method "echo" via package "IO::File" at ./echo.pl
line 10.
```

It should return:

```
TEST NOW
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo ARGV
```

is interpreted by Perl as "indirect object notation", i.e. the same as

```
ARGV->echo
```

[ARGV](http://p3rl.org/perlvar#ARGV)
 is a special file handle, its methods come form [IO::File](http://p3rl.org/IO::File) - but there's no `echo` method there.

Answer (score 1):

The book is [online here](http://www.greenteapress.com/perl/perl.pdf). This program is on page 4 (going by the page numbers). It is:

```
sub echo {
    print "@_\n";
}
echo @ARGV
```

So this is just a typo. You have `ARGV` where you wanted `@ARGV`.

That book is from 2003. A lot has changed in Perl since then. You might well be better off looking at [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for should be this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;


sub echo {
     my @params = @_;
     print "@params\n";
}

echo(@ARGV);
```